# Keep a script running through ssh after logout

Tags: linux, ssh, nohup

This is the first question that I post here. I tried to do a throughout search, but if I haven't (and the answer is obvious somewhere else), please just let me know.

I have a script that runs a program for me, here it is:

```
csv_file=../data/teste_nohup.csv
trace_file=../data/gnp.trace

declare -i n=100
declare -i p=1
declare -i counter=0

while [ $counter -lt 3 ];
do
n=100    
    while true
    do
      nice -19 sage gnptest.py ${n} ${p} | tee -a ${csv_file}
      notify-send "finished test gnp ${n} ${p}"
    done
done
```

So, what I'm trying to do is run the gnptest.py program a few times, and have the result be written to the csv_file.

The problem is, that depending on the input, the program may take a long time to complete. So I'd like to connect to the server over ssh, start the program, close the terminal, and check the output file from time to time.
I've tried nohup and disown. Nohup creates a huge nohup.out file, full with errors that I don't get while normally running the script (it complains about using the -lt operand, for example). But the biggest problem that I'm facing is that no command (nohup ou disown -h) is executing the program and sending the output to the file that I've specified in the csv_file variable, which is being done using the tee command. Also, none of them seem to continue running after I logout...

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You could try screen or dtach.

Comment: Or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)! :D

Comment: or use nohup to run the script in the background

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the quick replies!!! 
I tried screen and it worked like a charm!! I'm so happy!! Thank you @evading 
I can't use tmux because I'm not allowed to install software on the server that I'm using.
And as I stated before, I tried using nohup, but it just don't work for me.

But again, I really appreciated all the help!!

Answer (score 1):

i hv just joined so cannt add comment

Please try by using redirection instead of tee in script
And to get rid of Nohup.out  use following  to run script
`nohup script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

If above produces error use

`nohup script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @Jord. But nohup is no good for me, even with the redirection, because I print some information on the screen during the run of the program that I don't want to end up in my resulting file. I'll save your commands in case I need to use nohup.